# What is the difference between % and / in C?

Tags: c, math, operators

I am new to C and realized that I didn't quite understand the difference between `/` and `%`. It would be very helpful if you could explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: This is a C question, it's not Objective-C specific.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good explanation about the `%`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_Operation

Comment: Go through a book, or some other learning material. SO is not a place for asking such question

Answer (score 1):

"/" is used for division and "%" is used to calculate the remainder

e.g

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;

int divisionResult = a / b; //it's 3
int reminderResult = a % b; // it's 1 (which is the remainder of the division)
```

Comment: `%` is remainder, not modulo. E.g. `-5 % 3` produces the remainder from division, -2, but mathematicians would often prefer the “modulo” result to be 1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your comment - I've updated my answer. However I thought that the difference from modulo and reminder operators was only in the sign: with a remainder operator, the sign of the result is the same as the sign of the dividend while with a modulo operator the sign of the result is the same as the divisor. Why would the "modulo" of -5 % 3 be 1?

Comment: The distance between 1 and -5 is 6, a multiple of 3. For mathematicians, modulo congruence groups integers into subsets based on multiples of the modulus. For 3, the subsets are { …, -6, -3, 0, +3, +6,… }, { …, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7,… }, and { … -4, -1, 2, 5, 8,… }. The actual “thing” that is “x modulo 3” for a mathematician is the subset itself, not any particular member of it. However, we can use any member to represent the subset. It is often useful to choose a member that is between 0 and the modulus (including 0, not including the modulus), just because it makes some things simpler.

Comment: E.g., if we want to record information about congruences in an array, we want the array indices to be 0, 1, 2, not -1, 0, 1. That is largely a matter of convenience and not hugely important, since there are ways to work around it. But what is particularly annoying is that `%` does not return a unique result for a given modulo subset. E.g., -5 and 1 are congruent modulo 3, so we would want `-5 mod 3` and `1 mod 3` to produce the same thing, but `-5 % 3` produces -2 and `1 % 3` produces 1. And that is a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

depends where these are being used, they mean different things in different contexts

if you are doing arithmetic, then / means divide while % means mod.

/ division is how normal division works

% will give you the remainder of a division, eg 5 % 2 = 1, because 2 goes into 5 twice with a remainder of 1.

also this pretty much universal to all languages (probably a few exceptions that i dont know about)

Comment: `%` is just remainder, not mod. E.g. `-5 % 3` produces the remainder from division, -2, but mathematicians would often prefer the “modulo” result to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

`a / b` is the quotient.

`a % b` is the remainder, that is, a mod b.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is division, `%`is module, the integer remainder of a division.

Answer (score 0):

/ is used for division and % is used for modulus.

Example:

```
5 / 2 = 2
5 % 2 = 1
```